# Capture a Response from GET and Use it in the Next Request

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to use the response of `axios.get`, and use it in `axios.post`. How can I use the response as a header in the `POST` request?

I tried using `axios.post` with `headers` defined in the request config:

```js
var config = {
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'user': newUser.eid,
    'pass':'bd957c3fbb'
  }
}

/*
const axios = require('axios')

getCrumb() {
  return axios.get('https://jenkins.com/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)', config)
  .then(response => {
    return response
  })
}
*/


/* code to get jenkins crumb */
const getJenkinsCrumb = () => {
  try {
    return axios.get('https://jenkins.com/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)', config)
      .then((crumbValue) => {
        console.log(crumbValue.data);
      })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
getJenkinsCrumb();
```

I want use the response from the previous `GET` request (above) as a header in the `POST` call (below).

```js
var crumbHeader = {
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  }
}

/* post api to kick off the build */

try {
  return axios.post('https://abc123:bd95701859@jenkins.com/job/Non- PAR/job/Non-Prod-Jobs/job/uitest/job/TestJob/buildWithParameters?nodes=100000&clustername=clustername', crumbHeader)
    .then((postKickTest) =>{
      console.log(postKickTest.data);
    })
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Axios request config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) includes a `headers` property to specify the request's headers. The config can be specified as the 2nd argument of [`axios.post()`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config) (if using the two-argument signature) or the 3rd argument (if using the three-argument signature). This example demonstrates the two-argument signature of `axios.post()` that sets the `headers` with the dataresult of a previous request:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    async sendRequest() {
      const userResp = await axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users/2')
      await axios.post('https://reqres.in/api/users', {
        headers: userResp.data,
        data: {
          name: 'john doe',
          job: 'leader',
        }
      })
    },
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-dj5h0?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue)

---

**Side note:** The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a CORS header that can only be set by the server. It has no effect when sent from the client. It's possible you're incorrectly assuming that header is not reaching the server because it's not resolving a CORS issue.